# Unable to open existing Vue project in Dev Containers (Server certificate verification failed) error

Tags: vue.js, github, containers, vscode-extensions, docker-desktop

I am trying to open an existing Vue project in Dev Containers in VSCode but I keep getting the following error even when Docker Desktop is running in the background. Using a Mac with VSCode 1.78.0 and Dev Containers v0.299.0.

```
[15 ms] Dev Containers 0.299.0 in VS Code 1.78.0 (252e5463d60e63238250799aef7375787f68b4ee).
[15 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[27 ms] Setting up container for folder or workspace: /Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc
[27 ms] Context: desktop-linux
[28 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[28 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[87 ms] Server API version: 1.43
[87 ms] Start: Run: docker volume ls -q
[154 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.folder=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[199 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[244 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc
[288 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc
[332 ms] Start: Run: /private/var/folders/mh/1bwd48w90l94fgrtkf5n_q200000gr/T/AppTranslocation/D745C40C-2AE0-43DC-AF31-E3FC7B772B17/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/anonymous/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder /Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --mount-workspace-git-root true
[580 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v16.17.1. darwin 22.5.0 arm64.
[580 ms] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[605 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[1662 ms] Failed to fetch control manifest: HTTP 407: authenticationrequired
[1663 ms] Start: Run: /private/var/folders/mh/1bwd48w90l94fgrtkf5n_q200000gr/T/AppTranslocation/D745C40C-2AE0-43DC-AF31-E3FC7B772B17/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/anonymous/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/anonymous/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-fc334a92-f174-4b5e-a5b2-e02197610eb31690504071660 --workspace-folder /Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[1831 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v16.17.1. darwin 22.5.0 arm64.
[1831 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx version
[1906 ms] github.com/docker/buildx v0.11.0 687feca9e8dcd1534ac4c026bc4db5a49de0dd6e
[1906 ms] 
[1907 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[1908 ms] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[2170 ms] Failed to fetch control manifest: self signed certificate in certificate chain
[2171 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/Users/anonymous/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[2217 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type image mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.32.3-focal
[2262 ms] local container features stored at: /Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/node_modules/vscode-dev-containers/container-features
[2263 ms] Start: Run: tar --no-same-owner -x -f -
[2280 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /var/folders/mh/1bwd48w90l94fgrtkf5n_q200000gr/T/devcontainercli/container-features/0.46.0-1690504074434/Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-abc-d1b5750592662225e0f7b64d51b14bed4f9fd8be1ac44f9286db7054f900459f --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label /Users/anon/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer
[+] Building 0.3s (18/18) FINISHED                         docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.79kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.32.3-foc  0.0s
 => [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  1/14] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/p  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 145B                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  2/14] COPY ./zzz-root.c  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  3/14] COPY ./proxy.crt   0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  4/14] RUN update-ca-cer  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  5/14] RUN curl -fsSL ht  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  6/14] RUN echo "deb [ar  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  7/14] RUN apt-get updat  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  8/14] RUN curl -L https  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label  9/14] RUN groupadd node  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 10/14] RUN mkdir -p /etc  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 11/14] COPY .zshrc .p10k  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 12/14] RUN chown node:no  0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 13/14] ADD _npmrc /home/  0.0s
 => ERROR [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 14/14] RUN git clone --de  0.2s
------                                                                          
 > [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 14/14] RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ~/powerlevel10k:
0.090 Cloning into '/home/node/powerlevel10k'...
0.220 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
------
Dockerfile-with-features:44
--------------------
  42 |     ENV PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1
  43 |     
  44 | >>> RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ~/powerlevel10k
  45 |     
  46 |     # TODO: Debug why this stopped working, however Node v16 is already on this image.
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ~/powerlevel10k" did not complete successfully: exit code: 128
[2821 ms] Error: Command failed: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /var/folders/mh/1bwd48w90l94fgrtkf5n_q200000gr/T/devcontainercli/container-features/0.46.0-1690504074434/Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-abc-d1b5750592662225e0f7b64d51b14bed4f9fd8be1ac44f9286db7054f900459f --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label /Users/anon/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer
[2821 ms]     at Ute (/Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2008:1698)
[2821 ms]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2821 ms]     at async fC (/Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2007:1691)
[2821 ms]     at async n3 (/Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2007:610)
[2821 ms]     at async rre (/Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2024:3660)
[2821 ms]     at async Yf (/Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2024:4775)
[2821 ms]     at async Dne (/Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2156:12193)
[2821 ms]     at async Sne (/Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2156:11934)
[2823 ms] Exit code 1
[2825 ms] Command failed: /private/var/folders/mh/1bwd48w90l94fgrtkf5n_q200000gr/T/AppTranslocation/D745C40C-2AE0-43DC-AF31-E3FC7B772B17/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /Users/anon/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/anon/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-fc334a92-f174-4b5e-a5b2-e02197610eb31690504071660 --workspace-folder /Users/anon/Documents/GitHub/abc --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/anon/Documents/GitHub/abc --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/Users/anon/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/anon/Documents/GitHub/abc/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2825 ms] Exit code 1
```

P.S Tried installing previous 0.255.4 version of dev containers but couldn't make it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Docker Desktop to the latest version.

Restart Docker Desktop.

Clear Docker's cache:

```
docker system prune -a.
```

Use an alternate repository URL in Dockerfile or devcontainer.json:

```
RUN git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ~/powerlevel10k
```

Check for corporate proxy/firewall issues.

Verify Docker image configuration.

Try a different base image in Dockerfile.

Manually build the container using Docker CLI:

```
docker build -t <image_name>
```

Comment: I had to turn off the corporate proxy while opening in dev containers and then turn it on later which worked. Thanks for your suggestion!